# Windows Explorer: change default columns of the media-variant set of columns (photos, videos...)

Tags: windows-explorer, media, files-folders, column

When a folder contains photos and videos, explorer switches automatically which columns are displayed. I'm not questioning here whether I like the feature or not, so let's assume I liked that feature.

Now ok, but how do I choose which columns appear by default in this column set (not to mention that media usually appear in mosaic layout in the first place...).

For example, I like to have the last modification date column there all the time just next to the file name (whether or not I'm in detailed view to begin with or I switched to it from, let's say, the mosaic view).

I know the combo for the standard column-set: set columns, open folder settings, apply to all folders, blah blah. But, indeed here. Would that work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YES! It does work. When you apply settings to all folders, it's mentioned 'to all folders **of this type**'.

1. Change the view of your folder (whether it's standard or media, etc)...
2. In the ribbon, go to Show/hide / Options / Change folder and search options / View, then
3. Push 'Apply to folders'.
4. Confirm 'Do you want all folders **of this type** to match this folder's view settings?'.

There you go!